# What to do when a user edits an answer and makes mine look like it was copied?

Tags: discussion, answers

I once answered a question two minutes after another user answered it. The answer the user posted was quite different from mine, but soon after my answer was posted the user edited his answer by adding the information I added in my answer.

Now, what do I do because since the edit is less than 5 minutes old it will not show that the user edited it and it will make my answer look like it was copied?

Comment: I would sigh, leave a comment that if they copy information from your answer, they should at least leave proper attribution and delete my answer if all information is already answered elsewhere.

Comment: @Sumurai8 If you try they'll just tell you they didn't copy from your answer anyway i already deleted my answer

Comment: I know. It is annoying.

Comment: Related: [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Comment: Ultimately, yes it is annoying, but there is little that can be done.  First, unless it is an exact copy and paste from you, how do you know the earlier answerer didn't plan on adding that info originally.  In fact, he could have been typing it as you were typing yours.  That is the essence of the first link I posted, you get a quick answer to be "first" then work on expanding the answer in the first 5 minutes.

Comment: But your scenario does happen, but since it is difficult to prove, it isn't worth getting into a battle over it.  Making a comment will usually only escalate a situation and lead to finger pointing, at which time a mod will have to step in.  The best advice is just ignore it.